# Getting error while Creating apk with buildozer at root

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I am getting following error with while creating apk using buildozer.
I an using Ubuntu 16.0.4 and running as root

- Check that aidl can be executed
- Search for Aidl
- Run `/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools/20.0.1/aidl`
- Cwd None
- Aidl cannot be executed

  You might have missed to install 32bit libs
  Check http://buildozer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

  Check configuration tokens

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to run *buildozer* with *root*. The *.buildozer* folder will be created under $HOME e.g. */home/user-name/.buildozer*

With regards to the missing aidl file,
you need to run ***android*** in  */root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/* to update Android SDK, and aidl will be installed. You might have to run this a few times until you see a folder *build-tools* (*/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools*) with *subfolders 19.1.0, 23.0.1*, etc.

```
cd /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/
./android
```

[image: Img01 - build-tools]
[image]

Comment: when I run t  root@RItesh-PC:~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools# ./android
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: Hi Sir,I am getting this when running command buildozer -v android debug once Failed to rename directory /home/Ritesh/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools to /home/Ritesh/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/temp/ToolPackage.old01.
  Failed to create directory /home/Ritesh/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools
  Stopping ADB server failed (code 2).
  Starting ADB server failed (code 2).
  Done. 1 package installed.
 build-tools folder not found /home/Ritesh/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools

Comment: Run '/home/Ritesh/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android list sdk -u -e -a'
 Cwd /home/Ritesh/.buildozer/android/platform

Comment: Hi SIr, I am getting android: can't find sdkmanager.jar when I ran ./android .Please guide

Comment: Please refer to [Buildozer installation with Python2 or Python3 support](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer). Which versions of Ubuntu, JAVA, Cython and Kivy are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu is 16.04, cython is 0.21, openjdk version "1.8.0_162", Kivy 1.8.0

Comment: Are you able to solve the missing aidl file? I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Cython 0.25, jdk.1.8.0_162, and Kivy 1.10.0.

Comment: Yes I am able to fix missing aild